# How to find the largest sum with the smallest possible path in a tetrahedron of integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, dijkstra

First here is the question,

Say that an integer can be represented as a perfect sphere, in which the value of the sphere is equal to the integer it contains. The spheres are organized into a tetrahedral pyramid in which N = the length of the side, N being between 1 and 15. Pick (a possibly empty) subset of sphere's such that their sum of values is maximized. Note that the sphere can hold a negative value so it is not necessarily desirable to pick up every sphere. We do not want to disorganize the pyramid so we cannot take any one sphere without first taking the ones above it.

Input Format:

Line 1: integer N

Line 2: N(N+1)/2+1

Output Format:

Line 1: One integer, the maximum sum of values achievable

Sample Input:

```
3
5
-2 -7 
-3
1 0 8
0 3
2
```

Sample Output:

```
8
```

Here is a sample solution given to my understanding so far:

The best solution is shown as bold in the diagram bellow. It is not smart to take 1 because that would require taking -2, decreasing the total. There for 8, 3, and 2 should be taken because they outweigh -3 and -7.

[image: Sample Diagram of tetrahedron]

My question is,

How do I store the input so that I can retain the proper order? Or do i even need to? I am trying to use a queue but my program gets very lengthly because I have to find the sum for each possible path and then compare each sum to find the max. I am also having a lot of difficulty breaking the data up into the right pattern so I don't recount a number or take one out of sequence. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Can Dijkstra's algorithm be of any use in this case? If so, then how? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 3-dimensional array. To use your example:

```
A[0][0][0] = 5

A[1][0][0] = -2
A[1][1][0] = -3
A[1][0][1] = -7

A[2][0][0] = 1
A[2][1][0] = 0
A[2][2][0] = 2
A[2][0][0] = 0
A[2][1][0] = 3
A[2][0][0] = 8
```

The "above" relationship is simply a matter of index arithmetic: [i<sub>a</sub>, j<sub>a</sub>, k<sub>a</sub>] is above [i<sub>a</sub>+1, j<sub>a</sub>, k<sub>a</sub>], [i<sub>a</sub>+1, j<sub>a</sub>+1, k<sub>a</sub>] and [i<sub>a</sub>+1, j<sub>a</sub>, k<sub>a</sub>+1].

Comment: I See how using a multi-dimensinal array makes since. I will give that a go but wouldn't the arithmetic then depend on the order of the numbers. For a different problem if the numbers hold different values then you would need to find the max number again and a different arithmetic would be needed wouldn't it? How could I go about finding that for each unique input?

Comment: @KarmaPimp: I'm not sure what you mean by "a different arithmetic". I have described a data structure, not a search algorithm. If you need help with *every* part of this problem, then you should work on easier problems until this one seems less challenging.